# Why is this question getting votes to close?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons

I don't understand why "[Why is Applebee's in so many movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/70356/47145)" is getting votes to close. The question seems squarely within the purview of [on-topic questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), e.g. "Questions about a Movie or TV show's production" and not in the realm of

- Locating or purchasing Movies or TV content
- Technology questions about playing content
- Unimportant trivia that does not add to the understanding or
  appreciation of the title.
- TV news, sports and current affairs
- A title's release date or rumors about a specific title or series.
- Opinions about or recommendations for a movie or TV show

Comment: I don't agree with the Close votes that this question has on it, either.  I think that it's an interesting question followed by an excellent answer.  +1 :)

Comment: It got 2 closevote and rest people left it open. It seems fine and majority of community seems to appreciate it , no need to worry about closevote.

Comment: @AnkitSharma not "worried" just trying to get to know this particular SE community.

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy Your question was bit edge case so attracted few initial closevote but it's fine here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I *may* have voted to leave it open as it seems on-topic to me (since it specifically asks about [product-placement](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-placement)) but I can't recall for sure.

BUT...it would seem that some users think it is

> Unimportant trivia that does not add to the understanding or appreciation of the title.

I can *kind of* see the point but I think it's an interesting question nonetheless and deserves the excellent answer it has.

Comment: Totally agree!  It's an interesting question with an excellent answer.

Comment: We really need a proper definition of "trivia"!